# Is it better to end up the classpath variable with path separator or it's better without?

Tags: java, command-line, classpath

It's just a think that makes me wonder.In fact is not a real issue for me.
When I call the java(.exe) from command line is it better to end up the classpath variable with path separator (`;` in Windows or `:` in Unix)  or it's better without it.
It works both ways , I've seen it both ways - but much more often without.It's not clarified in java help.To me the end-up with separator looks more clear with.Could some of the ways to cause a problem?

**EDIT** : I suppose it's always a good idea to enclose the classpath in quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My 2c: separator should be placed between two other entities (to separate them). Having the separator at the end could possibly lead to fail when some code is trying to iterate over the array that was obtained by calling the split(SEPARATOR) method on the variable.

Obviously there is no correct answer to your question.